# Need Help Trouble Shooting A HP 8559A Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: troubleshooting, spectrum-analyzer, test-equipment

I recently acquired an HP 8559A spectrum analyzer however instead of the HP182T display it was supposed to have it shipped with an HP180C display. I am unable to get the display to output a signal (I only get a dot / vertical line). I believe this is because the 180C is not compatible with the analyzer. If anyone how is more knowledgable with this I would appreciate any help.

([image: Image of Display]

Please note the display shows an almost identical image if the calibrator is connected.

EDIT: After some additional research and testing it appears that the display is not sweeping (if I sweep manually I get what seems to be the correct signal).

Answer (score 2):

Not compatible according to the user's manual. The HP8559A requires 21.3 MHz IF, which is missing in the HP180C.

[image]

https://qsl.net/n9zia/test/HP8559A_Operating_an_Service_Manual.pdf

Comment: Would you be able to explain why a signal output connector makes it not compatible? I have read that section of the manual and I don't see how the outputs would affect what can be displayed.

Comment: They are using *input/output* somewhat ambiguously. The HP8559A may require a 21.4 MHz IF (intermediate frequency) signal *from* the display module.

Comment: So in theory, if that were the case I should be able to generate that signal and feed it into the device myself?

Comment: Maybe you could generate the signal externally, it would take some research.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are probably best answered at the HP-Agilent-Keysight mailing list.  This is a busy list filled with people who know much about most of the early HP equipment.  [Mailing List](http://HP-Agilent-Keysight-equipment@groups.io)